# React - parse comma separated user input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a input box that accepts user input and stores it as a string in an array. I want to be able to parse a pasted string in the input box, like `Value 1, Value 2, Value 3`. And have those values parsed then added separately to the array, (e.g) `["Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3"]`

There's probably a lot of different ways to do this, but I was looking at [Papaparse](https://www.papaparse.com/) and it certainly seems like a viable solution.

I could use some help on how to integrate this into my change handler that adds these values to the array.

I have a [sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/p5228pp3kj) that shows the current setup.

How can I parse a user entered list of values separated by a comma, and have each value added to an array while also displaying the value in a `<li>` element?

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Papa from "papaparse";

const list = "Value1 , value2, value3";
var results = Papa.parse(list);

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectorValues: [],
    selectorValue: ""
  };

  addSelectorValue = e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      selectorValues: [...prevState.selectorValues, prevState.selectorValue],
      selectorValue: ""
    }));
  };

  removeSelectorValue(index) {
    this.setState({
      selectorValues: this.state.selectorValues.filter((_, i) => i !== index)
    });
  }

  handleSelectorValueChange = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    //makes separate copy of array.
    this.setState({ selectorValue: value });
  };

  render() {
    const { selectorValues } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <div>
            <label>Selector Values:</label>{" "}
            <input
              type="text"
              value={this.state.selectorValue}
              placeholder="Enter selector value"
              onChange={this.handleSelectorValueChange}
              required={!this.state.selectorValues.length}
            />
            <button type="button" onClick={this.addSelectorValue}>
              Add
            </button>
          </div>
          <ul>
            {this.state.selectorValues.map((value, index) => {
              return (
                <li key={index}>
                  {value}
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    onClick={this.removeSelectorValue.bind(this, index)}
                  >
                    Remove
                  </button>
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Maybe you could use `value.split(",")` to get all the different values in an array?

Comment: @Tholle good point, what if there are no commas to act as a delimiter? Basically I want to simplify the process of adding these values, so they don't have to be added one by one, but instead can paste a list into the input box

Comment: `"hasNoComma".split(',')` will give you an array with one element `"hasNoComma"`, so that might work as well.

Comment: @Tholle split was easy enough to put in there, but visually I can't seem to get the entered values separated and displayed back to the user in the `<li>` elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the string method [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to split the `selectorValue` string up into substrings with `,` as delimiter and add those to your `selectorValues` array.

```
addSelectorValue = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.setState(({ selectorValues, selectorValue }) => ({
    selectorValues: [...selectorValues, ...selectorValue.split(",")],
    selectorValue: ""
  }));
};
```

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectorValues: [],
    selectorValue: ""
  };

  addSelectorValue = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState(({ selectorValues, selectorValue }) => ({
      selectorValues: [...selectorValues, ...selectorValue.split(",")],
      selectorValue: ""
    }));
  };

  removeSelectorValue(index) {
    this.setState({
      selectorValues: this.state.selectorValues.filter((_, i) => i !== index)
    });
  }

  handleSelectorValueChange = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    this.setState({ selectorValue: value });
  };

  render() {
    const { selectorValues } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.addSelectorValue}>
          <div>
            <label>Selector Values:</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              value={this.state.selectorValue}
              placeholder="Enter selector value"
              onChange={this.handleSelectorValueChange}
              required={!this.state.selectorValues.length}
            />
            <button>
              Add
            </button>
          </div>
          <ul>
            {this.state.selectorValues.map((value, index) => {
              return (
                <li key={index}>
                  {value}
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    onClick={this.removeSelectorValue.bind(this, index)}
                  >
                    Remove
                  </button>
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```